# What are FileTransformTaskV2 Variable substitution rules in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
 System.Debug: true
 one: actual-value
 Two: actual-value
 MappedValue: actual-value

steps:
  - task: FileTransform@2
    displayName: V2 - Transform
    env:
      Three: actual-value
      four: actual-value
      five: $(MappedValue)
      Six: $(MappedValue)
    inputs:
      folderPath: ./
      jsonTargetFiles: settings.json
      xmlTargetFiles: ''
      xmlTransformationRules: ''

  - pwsh: "Get-ChildItem Env:"
 
  - publish: settings.json
    artifact: settings.json
```

and the following settings.json file

```
{
    "one":"default",
    "two":"default",
    "three":"default",
    "four":"default",
    "five":"default",
    "six":"default"
}
```

Now I was hoping that the file transform task will be able to substitute all the value in the settings file but in reality only "one" is replaced.

Few thing to note:

1. ONE and TWO are set as env variables as seen in the list
2. Only ONE get replaced in settings.json but TWO does not
3. Two is define as Pascal case but is lower case in settings file
4. one and Two both appear in uppercase in env variables listed
5. Three, four , five and six are mapped to task environment variables
6. mapped variables also do not get transformed in the settings

So my question is what are the rules for transform task to be able to replace values in settings file? and why only one works and no other one works even they are mapped to env variables all with upper case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacement is done based on the Pipeline Variable, not env variables.

Take a look on this:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
 System.Debug: true
 one: actual-value
 two: actual-value
 MappedValue: actual-value
 three: $(MappedValue)
 four: actual-value
 five: $(MappedValue)
 Six: $(MappedValue)

steps:
  - task: FileTransform@2
    displayName: V2 - Transform
    inputs:
      folderPath: ./
      jsonTargetFiles: settings.json
      xmlTargetFiles: ''
      xmlTransformationRules: ''

  - pwsh: "Get-ChildItem Env:"
 
  - publish: settings.json
    artifact: settings.json
```

and I got:

```yaml
{
    "one": "actual-value",
    "two": "actual-value",
    "three": "actual-value",
    "four": "actual-value",
    "five": "actual-value",
    "six": "default"
}
```

Beacuse replacement is case sensitive, `six` was not replaced.

Comment: Thanks  @Krzysztof Madej. The [documentation here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/FileTransformV2) does not mention this but looking at [this source](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/e59e17f604af4b78560536fb3c191f29a99f59d1/Tasks/Common/webdeployment-common-v2/fileTransformationsUtility.ts#L114) it appears that this task should be looking at the environment  variables too.

Comment: Well, I found this there `    var envVarObject = createEnvTree(tl.getVariables());
` however I'm not sure what `tl.getVariables(` returns.

Comment: What is the difference between FileTransform@1 and FileTransform@2?

Comment: You will find this on remarks [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/file-transform-v2?view=azure-pipelines#remarks). In one project for instance I stayed with @1 because @2 fails with json.